# Overwriting default app icons (SVG or Fonticon?)

Tags: css, angular, svg, sass, building

I have an application that's currently using iconmoon for all the icons (buttons etc.) in my application but I would like to be able to make the icons easy to change for when parameterizing the application for a client.

What's the "best" route to take in these situations?

I have thought about the letting clients provide an override sass file that would import their own set of icons (iconmoon etc) and overwrite any existing classes but that doesn't feel "right".

Alternatively, I could also export the iconmoon library as svg files and define classes with the svg as background images. That would give clients the ability to just provide with new svg files that would just overwrite the default svg files during the build process.

The application in question is an Angular 6 app so Angular CLI is used for the build process and the file replace is done by a java building process that triggers the Angular CLI build.

Edit: This is more of a SVG vs fonticons argument.

Answer (score 1):

As for "easiest" (contrary to the "best"): have you considered using simple fallback character resolution mechanism of `font-family`?

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Icon Overrides'; (...)}
@font-face { font-family: 'Icon Defaults'; (...)}

.icon { font-family: "Icon Overrides", "Icon Defaults"; }
```

Provided both font files has uniform icon ↔ code point mapping, you'll get possibility to redefine some (or all) icons in the first font; characters not defined there will be looked for in the second. (You can even use single font-family for whole app, like `html { font-family: "Icon Overrides", "Icon Defaults", "Base text font", "Some fallback text font", "And so on", sans-serif; }`, again, provided icon font uses sane mapping to corresponding Unicode points or uses private use area.

---

As for "is font better for iconography than inlined SVG" (i.e. the "best route" you've asked for), I'd stick with current trend: use SVG when possible, but discussing it's benefits and maintainability in given environment is too broad for such a simple answer.  Also, asking questions such as "what do you think is the best for X" might be too vague for this site.

Comment: The questions is mainly what makes it easier to maintain a large app with a ton of icons that would need to be replaced depending on client needs and need to be easy to adapt during an automated (large) build process.

Answer (score 0):

First you shouldn't forget that maybe they want to return it to default, that wouldn't be achievable easily if you overwrite them.

I would go with map of: what's it used for : icon name : icon path (original) : current icon path

Then you can make some simple design where you enlist all icons from that map and allow them to change current icon path. If they click "return to default" you can just change current icon path with original one.

Point of this is that you just stick with map when rendering, that way app will be more module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the build process spits out different packages for each client. The client doesn't have the ability to change any icons after the build process since all they get is a war file. I do icon changes myself. Your solution relies on what method of handling files though?